# Multiplication by a rational number while doing row transformation

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to find rank of a matrix by converting it into row echelon form. I have a doubt that can we  multiply a rational number to any row and add this to other row? Is there anything wrong in this?
For instance if we have 6 in first row first column and want to make it 1 then can we multiply that row by 1/6 and make it 1?
I know that we can not do multiplication with zero in this process.
You may find it as a silly doubt but Please help me.

Comment: You can multiply by a rational number.

Comment: Thank you very much.